# Use special template for the first post in the loop

Tags: posts, loop, templates, query-posts

I want to use a special template for the first post in a loop.

So I tried this:

```
<?php 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        if( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) :
            get_template_part( 'template/first', get_post_format() );
        else :
            get_template_part( 'template/post', get_post_format() );
        endif;
    endwhile; 
?>
```

It doesn't return the first post, but it returns other posts.

Comment: define "doesn't work". what happens?

Comment: I can't get first post, but I see others posts

Comment: are you sure the template file you are trying to load exists in that location?

Comment: You could test Milo's question by using template/first in the 'else' part of the if statement, just as a test to see if it renders for the remaining posts.